# Wanting to check a special case of fibres of points over $\mathbb{C}$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, schemes

So I have recently been studying fibres of points of morphisms of schemes. Hartshorne has an exercise doing a specific example of one of these. The exercise is II 3.10. Suppose we are given a morphism $f: \text{Spec }B \longrightarrow \text{Spec } A$ of affine schemes and $y \in Y$ is some point in Y. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the prime ideal of $A$ corresponding to the point $y$. Then the points in the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$ correspond to the prime ideals of
$$
B \otimes_{A} \kappa(y)
$$
where $\kappa(y)$ is the residue field of $y$. I am comfortable with that fact, and I proved that primarily with commutative algebra and the Going-Up theorem. I am feeling slightly uncomfortable using it in a geometric context though.

The exercise I mentioned above uses the example of a morphism,
$$
f: \text{Spec }k[s, t]/(s - t^{2}) \longrightarrow \text{Spec }k[s].
$$
with $k$ an algebraically closed field and the morphism determined by the morphism of rings given by the composotion
$$
k[s] \stackrel{\text{inclusion}}{\longrightarrow} k[s, t] \stackrel{\text{quotient}}{\longrightarrow} k[s, t]/(s - t^{2})
$$

I am asked to describe the fibres of the points in $k[s]$ by breaking it into three cases: The point corresponding to the $0$ element of $k$, the closed points corresponding to the non-zero elements of $k$, and the generic point.

Is someone able to see if my argument looks valid? I am a little uncomfortable that I haven't manipulated the tensor products correctly also. The following is my attempt:
We will consider the closed points of $\text{Spec } k[s]$ first. These correspond to maximal ideals of $k[s]$ which are of the form $(s - a )$ and which we denote by $\mathfrak{m}_{a}$. Consider first the case of $a \neq 0$. We would like to examine the spectrum of the ring
\begin{align*}
k[s, t] / (s - t^{2}) \otimes_{k[s]} k &\simeq k[s, t] / (s - t^{2}) \otimes_{k[s]} k[s] / \mathfrak{m}_{a} \\
& \simeq k[t] \otimes_{k[s]} k[s] / \mathfrak{m}_{a} \\
& \simeq k[t] / \left( \mathfrak{m}_{a}  k[t] \right)
\end{align*}
Now the inclusion morphism above fixes $s$, and so the ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{a} k[t]$ is the ideal $$(\pi(s) - a)k[t] \simeq (t^{2}- a)k[t]$$ which is the ideal $(t^{2} - a) \subseteq k[t]$. I claim that the resulting quotient ring $k[t]/(t^{2} - a)$ has two prime ideal. Indeed any such prime ideal will correspond to a prime ideal of $k[t]$ containing $(t^{2} - a)$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, we have a unique factorization,
$$
t^{2} - a = (t - \beta)( t - \gamma),
$$
and it is a simple task to check that if $a \neq 0$ then $\beta \neq \gamma$. The points of the fiber then correspond to the prime ideals $(t - \beta)$ and $(t - \gamma)$. Observe also that we didn't invoke the fact that $a \neq 0$ until now, so the same argument as above works for the case $a = 0$ except now we only have the one prime ideal $(t)$. Indeed the fiber is given by the scheme $\text{Spec}\left( k[t] / (t^{2}) \right)$ which is certainly not reduced since $k[t] / (t^{2})$ has a niloptent element.

Finally, we consider the case of the generic point $\eta \in Y$. The residue field is $k(s)$, the field of rational functions in $s$ (the transcendence degree $1$ extension of $k$). Then we have
$$
k(s) \otimes_{k[s]} k[s, t] / (s - t^{2}) \simeq k(s)[t] / (s - t^{2}).
$$
which is an extension of degree $2$ over $k(s)$. Indeed a basis over $k(s)$ as a vector space is given by $\{1, t  \}$.

Comment: In your very first definition of $f$, you have confused the variables. If you project to the $s$-axis, you should have $s-t^2$, otherwise you get a boring one-to-one map.

Comment: Assuming it is $s-t^2$, all you calculations are correct. This of course goes well with our intuition. You project the parabola $y=x^2$ to the $y$-axis. Of course the general fibre consists of two points, while the fibre at the critical point is only a singleton, but of multiplicity $2$.